# How does Ruby allow method param defaults to be derived from earlier params?

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters, computer-science

In Ruby, params passed first in the list can be the used to define defaults for later params.

```
class Buddy
  def test opts, spec = opts[:red]
    puts spec
  end
end


n = Buddy.new
n.test( {:red => 3} )
```

What wizardry does this?
Are all params loaded serially? Is this behaviour only for `proc`, but not `lambda`?

Answer (score 1):

Method calls cause the arguments to be assigned to the parameter variables:

```
    do_stuff(10, 20)  #method call
def do_stuff( x, y )  #method definition

resulting assignments: x = 10, y = 20
```

Parameter variables are local variables.  After a value gets assigned to a local variable, the local variable can be accessed.  Parameter variable assignment doesn't seem to work any differently than writing:

```
x = {a: 1, b: 2}
y = x[:a]

puts x, y

--output:--
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
1
```

> Is this behaviour only for proc

Where is there a proc in your example?  In any case,

```
func = Proc.new do |x, y=x[:a]| 
  puts x, y  
end

func.call({a: 1, b: 2})

--output:--
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
1
```

lambdas:

```
func = lambda do |x, y=x[:a]| 
  puts x, y  
end

func.call({a: 1, b: 2})

--output:--
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
1
```

So parameter variable assignment works the same way for methods, procs, and lambdas.